# Doing #ifdef DEBUG and #define func() right?

Tags: c

This doesn't seem quite right, but it's the best I could do. Is there a way to do this better? My goal is to use DEBUG when I'm developing by doing a 'cc -DDEBUG' at the prompt.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define ptrValues ptrvaluesRemote
#else
#define ptrValues ptrValuesLocal
#endif

ptrLinks = (struct sLinkDescriptionLayout*) ptrValues();
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps use NDEBUG (as used in assert.h) instead of making up your own.  Also note that unless you put an ifdef around the two functions you might get a linkage warning (as one of the functions might be unused).  A warning is undesirable, but so is putting the ifdef around the functions, which will result in one of the functions not being compiled and in time the function may rot.

Note that you might achieve the same end using the tool-chain to modify the symbol table.

Another alternative would be to name the two functions the same in two separate files and link one or the other as required - that would be a cleaner solution, but would need documenting.

Also...

Perhaps make `ptrLinks` and `ptrValuesEtc` the same type so that a cast is unnecessary.

Consider whether `ptrLinks` and `ptrValuesEtc` are correctly named:

- they appear to the uninitiated (me) to mean different things;
- also, one is a function and the other a pointer but their form is the same.

Comment: I like this answer. Do you see any problems with using NDEBUG on Windows?

Comment: There is no problems with using NDEBUG on windows. It is used in DevStudio and is defined for release builds.

Comment: I disagree with the idea of using NDEBUG. As there is a difference between Debug/Release and NDEBUG/ ! NDEBUG. The NDBUG flag basically turns assert on/off. I can see a situation where you want to turn asserts on in release mode to help diagnose a problem that only happens in release build.

Comment: Great input. Thank you both. I have thought about wrapping the two functions in `#ifdef` but I _am_ concerned about having the function code branch, one for production and one for debug. It's a tangential topic, but a good one.

Comment: Keep assertion control (`-DNDEBUG`) separate from the rest of your debugging (so I agree 100% with @LokiAstari — and upvoted his comment too).

Answer (score 3):

Not much prettier, but maybe preferable depending on how you need to use it later:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_FLAG 1
#else
#define DEBUG_FLAG 0
#endif

ptrLinks = (struct sLinkDescriptionLayout*) DEBUG_FLAG?ptrValuesLocal():ptrValuesRemote();
```

The C preprocessor is simultaneously fantastic and terrible.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a ternary operator in the preprocessor

Answer (score 3):

I recommend making the function name macro into a function-like macro instead of an object-like macro — give it an empty argument list.  Also, it is usually best to keep the logic positive, so use `#ifdef` rather than `#ifndef`.  This is hardly critical here, but in more complex situations, it is a good guideline to follow.

These observations lead to:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#define ptrValues() ptrValuesLocal()
#else
#define ptrValues() ptrvaluesRemote()
#endif

ptrLinks = (struct sLinkDescriptionLayout*) ptrValues();
```

Personally, I would also have:

```
 typedef struct sLinkDescriptionLayout sLinkDescriptionLayout;
```

Then I wouldn't need the `struct` in the cast:

```
ptrLinks = (sLinkDescriptionLayout *)ptrValues();
```

I'd probably go for a shorter name, too, (perhaps `LinkDesc`, but it depends on what the other names in the code are) but that's very much less critical.